# I need to understand whether the following two Bessel function identities are equal? I have found both of them on the internet.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I saw the following two identities and wanted to know whether they can be proved to be equivalent. Can you help with this?

$$
J_{0}(a)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos⁡(a\sin ϕ)\mathrm dϕ
$$
([Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function))

and
$$
J_{0}(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos⁡(a\cosϕ)\mathrm dϕ
$$
where $a=\text{const}$ and $J_{0}$ is a Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Why did you revert the edits to a worse-looking version?

Comment: Hi Gray, I corrected the equations. Thanks! I thought I need to approve your editing and didn't know it is automatically accepted.

Comment: Hint: change variables $\phi = 2\pi - \psi$ in the first integral to switch between $\int_0^\pi$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}$.  Can you find change of variables to switch between $\int_0^\pi$ and $\int_0^{\pi/2}$?  And finally a change of variables to switch from $\sin$ to $\cos$ in the $\int_0^{\pi/2}$ integrals.

Answer (score 1):

First, remark that due to the evenness of the integrand in the first identity, we may write
$$J_0(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos(z\sin\phi)\mathrm d\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(z\sin\phi)\mathrm d\phi$$
Now use the change of variable $\theta=\pi/2-\phi$ to get
$$J_0(z)=\frac{-1}{2\pi}\int_{3\pi/2}^{-\pi/2}\cos(z\sin(\pi/2-\theta))\mathrm d\theta \\ =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\cos(z\cos\theta)\mathrm d\theta$$
And because the integrand is $2\pi$ periodic, its integral over any interval of length $2\pi$ is the same, hence
$$J_0(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(z\cos\theta)\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: Thanks, K.defaoite!